# Как сделать конкатенацию массива в переменной c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как сделать конкатенацию массива в  переменной

```
string a[4] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
int b;
```

Comment: По очереди, в цикле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы имели ввиду конкатенацию, то так:

```
#include <numeric>

std::string a[4] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
int b = std::stoi(std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::string{})); 
std::cout << b; //1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто перевести в число по отдельности то,попробуйте как то так:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);i++){
 int number = atoi(a[i].c_str()); //atoi - метод перевода строки в число. 
}
```

Ну или int number = std::stoi(str);

Comment: Но раз уж работаете со строками `string`, то не нужно этих лишних телодвижений с переводом в `char*`, есть куда более приятная и **более информативная** функция [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @Harry спасибо за информацию, учту.